# Capturing and logging broken links on a custom 404 page

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http-status-code-404

I am trying to create a customer 404 page in php that captures and can log into a database the page that was requested.  I have this in my .htaccess file already:

ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com/notfound.php

What I am trying to do is append the requested URI to as a query string to the URL.  I have tried this:

ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com/notfound.php?url=%{REQUEST_URI}

but the URL shows the literal text that I put in above.  So I figured I would need some sort of flag at the end like [QSA] or something but all attempts result in a server error 500.

My ultimate goal is to capture the attempted broken link and the referring URL (which I can get from $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']) on the notfound.php page and log this into my database where I can pull a report of all links, hyperlinked or called via AJAX, that are broken or missing.  I am able to do everything except get the requested URI of the actual link that caused the 404 error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't use `ErrorDocument 404` with `http://` in the target to avoid full redirect, like this:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /devsite/notfound.php
```

Then original 404 URI will be available to you as `$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`

Comment: Not sure if I follow...  If I put "ErrorDocument 404 /notfound.php" in the .htaccess file, I get a 404 on that request.  Putting "ErrorDocument 404 http://mywebsite.com/notfound.php" in .htaccess works, but $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = /mywebsite/notfound.php.  I am currently developing in localhost, not sure if that makes a difference or not.  My actual ErrorDocument statement is: ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/devsite/notfound.php which will be changed to the server when it goes live.

Comment: You need to give full path from DocumentRoot. So you need to use: **`ErrorDocument 404 /devsite/notfound.php`**

Comment: aahhh, I knew it was something I was overlooking.  Shoulda known better (facepalm).  Thanks!!